# Multiplying matrix by random vector

Tags: matrices, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let there be an arbitrary matrix $A=(a_{i,j})_{M\times N}$ and a vector $V=(x_{i})_{N}$

Where for each $i\in\{1,2,...,N\}$ we have independently distribiuted
$$x_{i}=\begin{cases} 1 &\text{with probability } p\\0 &\text{with probability } q \end{cases}$$

Of course $p+q=1$

and for all $i,j$ we have $(a_{i,j})\in\{0,1\}$
Every row has exactly $r$ ones, ($r\in[0,N]$)
There is no two same rows.

We denote new vector $U=A\cdot V=(y_{1},...,y_{M})^T$

Let $f(U)=\max_{i\in \{1,2,...,M\}}y_{i}$

> Is there any formula/method to calculate the distribution $P(f(U)\le t)$? For example just by looking at the matrix?

I only was managed to see that:
$P(f(U)\le t)=P(y_{1}\le t)\cdot ... \cdot P(y_{M}\le t)$?

However i don't know whether is this a good idea to solve the problem .

Regards

Comment: You can get a vertically centred ellipsis with proper spacing from binary operators like $\cdot$ using `\cdots`.

Comment: Your product formula doesn't hold. It assumes that the events $y_i\le t$ are independent; but they aren't, since they all depend on the $x_i$.